# Distinguish color of the digits in an image

Tags: python, opencv, colors, computer-vision

I am working on a task where I want to distinguish the digits in an image based on their colors. For example, in the images below, digits are divided into black, red, green and blue colors.

[image]

[image]

I have divided these image into sixteen small patches, and each patch contains one digit. My goal is to cluster the patches based on the color of the digits they have, so in the end there are 4 clusters for black, red, green and blue digits. 
I am sure there are many approaches to do this, but I would like to know the best course of actions to complete this task efficiently. All suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: Until now the approach which is working best is that after dividing the image into sixteen small patches, I am removing the background of the digits to remove the noise due to background. After that I am converting the digit patches into CMYK color space and calculate the average CMYK for all pixels. After this I get average CMYK for each of the 16 patches. Than I use Kmeans clustering to cluster the digits into 4 clusters based on their average CMYK values, but it still make errors. I would like to know more suggestions.

Comment: K-means is sensitive to outliers, which is why you may be getting errors. Try different clustering method like K-medoids.

Comment: K-medoids did not work very well too because of the fact that you need to choose data points as the initial centroids and in my case there is no way for us to choose 4 centroids from random image patches. If we choose wrong centroids, it does not work very well.

Comment: How about [Hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering)?

Comment: Your input images are very noisy, also jpeg compression artifacts are very visible, these must be helping by creating garbage in to produce garbage out. What have you tried to improve the image quality - can you completely avoid JPEG compression artifacts (i.e. NOT use jpeg format), or work with less (i.e. higher quality) JPEG compression so artifacts aren’t so destructive?

Comment: Some suggestions to try: I would work in HSV color space (1D clustering over the hue channel). For the clustering (given your noisy data) try to choose the "best" pixels: remove low intensity, high intensity and low saturation pixels.

Comment: Hi guys,
Thanks for the suggestions. We have completed this task by pre-processing the images using white balancing and color enhancements and than used CMYK averages for each patch to cluster the patches using K-mean clustering algorithm. The only missing piece was to pre-process the images as suggested by @barny.